# How to update or retrieve software for my webcam?

Tags: webcam, software-update

How can I update or retrieve the software needed to run the integrated webcam on my HP Pavilion laptop? I lost access to the original program for it after switching out my hard drive. Or can I install a generic webcam program? Thanks.

Comment: A Generic Program should work. if not if you listed the model number you may be able to get the software back. I used a Generic webcam program on a HP all in one a couple years back and it worked flawlessly,

Comment: Are the drivers not available on the HP website?

Answer (score 0):

If you  have the old hard drive and can still read its contents, look for a folder on it named SWSetup, your webcam software installer will be in one of those folders, they are not always clearly labeled, look in each folder for clues at what the software is. Mine is located in the Youcam folder.

If you do not have access to the old drive, the only recourse to get the original Free software back is to use your HP Recovery Media to reinstall the OS and all original software.

Yes you can [install YouCam Standard for a small fee](http://www.cyberlink.com/products/youcam/features_en_US.html?&r=1)